# @RequestParam array mapping issues

Tags: java, spring

I'm doing a REST service with Spring MVC framework.

I have a method:

```
@RequestMapping("/rest/{tableName}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody CustomObject query(
    @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName, 
    @RequestParam(value="columns", required=false) String[] columns,
    @RequestParam(value="filter", required=false) String[][] filters) {
...
}
```

Well, I want filters to be a bidimensional array which an specific structure:

If I do a request with this url `/rest/table?filter=filter1,filter2&filter=filter3` I have then `filters = {{filter1, filter2}, {filter3}}`

If I do with: `/rest/table?filter=filter1&filter=filter2` I have: `filters = {{filter1},{filter2}}`

My question is...

why if I call:`/rest/table?filter=filter1,filter2` I get: `filters = {{filter1},{filter2}}` and not: `filters = {{filter1,filter2}}`?

Is there any way for get the last array instead of the first in that situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sending lists of items in the URL is tricky. In general, the request

```
/rest/table?filter=A&filter=B
```

and

```
/rest/table?filter=A,B
```

will both get parsed as if A and B are individual parameters. This is because Spring's default `WebDataBinder` is configured to split parameters lists on commas. You can disable this default configuration by adding some binder initialization code to your controller.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.registerCustomEditor(
        String[].class,
        new StringArrayPropertyEditor(null)); 
}
```

Now the data binding process for parameter lists coming in over HTTP will *not* be split on the comma, and be interpreted as separate items. This will likely produce the behavior you're looking for, so that comma-delimited parameter lists will be treated as a single array parameter rather than N separate single-item array parameters.

Comment: What if I want a pipe "|" to be the delimiter instead of comma "," ?

Comment: @Misha, how could this be done for a `@RequestParam` that is `List<String>`? What class to pass to binder.registerCustomEditor then?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of only disabling the usage of comma as separator, for overriding the use of a comma delimiter with pipe I did the following:

1 - Created a class that extends PropertyEditorSupport setting the delimiter as pipe.

```
public class StringListPropertyEditor extends PropertyEditorSupport {

    public static final String DEFAULT_SEPARATOR = "\\|";

    @Override
    public void setAsText(String text) throws IllegalArgumentException {

        List<String> theList = Arrays.asList(text.split(DEFAULT_SEPARATOR));

        setValue(theList);

    }


}
```

2 - Created a InitBinder at my controller which register my PropertyEditor as CustomEditor

```
@InitBinder
    public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.registerCustomEditor(List.class, new StringListPropertyEditor());
    }
```