# array as a PathVariable in Spring MVC

Tags: jquery, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use `@RequestMapping` in form of (or different) :

```
  @RequestMapping(value = {"/dirA/{listOfids}" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

so that path `/dirA/2/3/4/5/6(...)` will be still resolved into it?
Or what would be the best way to handle similar request and pass array of some ids/properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot do that via a `PathVariable`, but you can pass an array via a `RequestParam`

Check [How to pass an array within a query string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243051/how-to-pass-an-array-within-a-query-string) and [@RequestParam array mapping issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695817/requestparam-array-mapping-issues) for more info.

Comment: @xwhyz, You should provide upvote or even accept the answer if you find it useful! this is why people will get motivation to answer your questions!

Answer (score 0):

Not in the way you're describing. You can do something like this though

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/dirA/{listOfIds}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public List<MyObject> find(@PathVariable Integer[] listOfIds)
```

And then use the path `/dirA/2,3,4,5,6` (i.e. with commas instead of slashes)

Comment: Can you tell how to access in controller if i am passing data as ["download_1551771319518.jpg","download%20(1)_1551771319518.jpg"]?